# Time complexity of while loops

Tags: java, time, time-complexity, big-o

how would I go about finding the time complexity of this code fragment? My main question is if I add or multiply the two while loops together or are they two separate things?

```
void Start()
{

    queueB.Enqueue(1);
    queueB.Enqueue(2);
    queueB.Enqueue(3);
    queueB.Enqueue(4);

    count = queueB.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < queueB.Count; i++)
    {

        while (queueB.Count > 1)
        {
            queueC.Enqueue(queueB.Dequeue());
        }

        queueA.Enqueue(queueB.Dequeue());



        while (queueC.Count > 1)
        {
            queueB.Enqueue(queueC.Dequeue());
        }

        queueA.Enqueue(queueC.Dequeue());

    }
```

Comment: Complexity is O`(n^2)` because you have a outer for loop which will iterate over n times and in worst case each of the inner while loops will iterate over n times each so if you put it to equation it will be `(n x (n + n)) => (n x 2n) => 2n^2` from a normalization perspective `2n^2 == n^2` hence `O(n^2)`

Comment: `O(x) + O(y) = O(max(x, y))`, where `max(...)` should be understood as an order function that takes two functions (!) as argument and returns the "larger" function, i.e. the function that grows faster asymptotically.

Comment: great thanks for the explanation as well